# Card set sorting - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to order a user input, set of cards (Not deck) from lowest to highest A-K. I am not very experienced with python, and don't know much of the terminology and functions. I am trying to keep the code simple and basic.

Here is what I have:

```
A = 1
J= 11
Q = 12
K = 13

alist = sorted(input("Type your card set: "))

#it prints 1,11,12,and 13 instead of A,K,Q,J

print(alist)
```

How do I change 1,11,12,13 back to A,K,Q,J before printing?

Comment: Could you post an example input & output?

Comment: Yes, 
    Type your card set: 7,6,5,4,3,2,A,K,Q,J,10,9,8 #user input
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] #the print

Comment: You should have a look at dictionaries. They will help you!

Comment: You should have a look at [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). I would recommend, though, that you go through a Python tutorial in order to gain experience on a more solid basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dict

```
d={'A': 1,
'J': 11,
'Q' : 12,
'K': 13}
alist ='7,6,5,4,3,2,A,K,Q,J,10,9,8'
alist=alist.split(',')
```

Creating the new list based on the input if it is a digit (like 1,2) then we do not need to refer to the dict else if it is like('A','K'etc.) we need the mapping from the dict defined above and then sort the new dict form

```
new_list=sorted([int(i) if i.isdigit() else d[i] for i in alist]) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

To convert back to 'A.J,k' Create a new dict with keys as 1 as values as 'A' etc

```
d_new=dict(zip(d.values(),d.keys()))
```

Replace the values. Do an iteration similar to one we did earlier if the value is 1 or 11 then lookup in d_new dict for the corresponding mapping

```
for i,value in enumerate(new_list,0):
    if value in d_new.keys():
        new_list[i]=d_new[value]
print(new_list) # ['A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K']
```

Comment: I tried running the code, and it gives me the error that new_list is not defined. If you could explain how the code works, that would be great thanks. I'm just trying to understand how some of this code works.

Comment: @A.doj Edited my response.